# The number of procedures needed to make an arbitrary permutation to the identity

Tags: combinatorics

Let $\sigma=(a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_{2016})$ be a permutation of $\{1,2,\cdots,2016\}$.
We split the elements of $\sigma$ so that every consecutive subsequence has the longest length as possible. Then, we reverse the order of each subsequences.
For example, for a 5-permutation $(4,1,3,5,2)$, the result would be $(4,5,3,1,2)$.

We continue this process until we get the strictly decreasing sequence $(2016,\cdots,2,1)$. The question is: what are the possible number of procedures to get to this final stage?

I presume that the answer would be all natural numbers from 1 to the maximum value possible, but how can I prove/disprove this?

Comment: Regarding the procedure, are you splitting $\sigma$ into consecutive *increasing* subsequences?

Comment: For showing that the number of possible steps required can be anything up to the maximum, suppose the maximum number of steps required is $M$, and let $\sigma_0$ be a permutation that requires $M$ steps.  Let $\sigma_i$ be the permutation we have after $i$ steps.  Then $\sigma_i$ requires $M - i$ steps, and so we get every natural number from $0$ to $M$.